# Create Neo4j property uniqueness constraint, when an index on that property already exists

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I want to ensure that a node property has a uniqueness constraint, however it may already have an index. This is on a live database, so I did not want to delete the index and then create the constraint because I suspect performance would be affected while the index is rebuilt. Any ideas?

Comment: you already know the solution, you have to drop the index and create a unique constraint, the performance will be affected but very depending on the amount of nodes you have